# How to display Checkbox in DataTable body Vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a Vue application which is built using Vuetify and I want to create a table where cell content is a checkbox `v-checkbox` but it renders html string instead of checkbox inside table body.

I use `v-data-table` as a main table.

For illustration:
[image]

My Code:

```html
<v-data-table :headers="headers"
              :items="menuaccess"
              :search="search"
              sort-by="alias"
              class="elevation-3"
              v-html="value"> <--- I tried add this but not working

<!-- other code -->
```

Data source snippet (I will get data from API later) :

```js
headers: [
    { text: '', align: 'start', value: 'alias' },
    { text: 'ASSET_EDIT', value: '<v-checkbox class="mx-2" label="Example"></v-checkbox>' },
    { text: 'ASSET_VERIFICATION', value: '<v-checkbox class="mx-2" label="Example"></v-checkbox>' },
    { text: 'ASSET_VIEW', value: '<v-checkbox class="mx-2" label="Example"></v-checkbox>' },
    { text: 'CUSTOMER_COMPANY_EDIT', value: '<v-checkbox class="mx-2" label="Example"></v-checkbox>' },
],
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to place code inside slot template.

```html
<v-data-table :headers="headers"
              :items="menuaccess"
              :search="search"
              sort-by="alias"
              class="elevation-3">
      <template v-slot:item.property_name="{ item }">
        <v-simple-checkbox v-model="item.property_name" />
      </template>
</v-data-table>
```

Where `property_name` is name of the property on your data object.

Read more about it in the [documentation](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/#simple-checkbox).